# How to apply different color in AppBar Title Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use my custom color for `AppBar` header. The `AppBar` has title 'My AppBar'. I am using white as my primary theme color. It works well for the bar but the 'title' of the `AppBar` is also using same 'white' color'

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import * as Colors from 'material-ui/styles/colors';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';

   const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    textColor: Colors.darkBlack,
    primary1Color: Colors.white,
    primary2Color: Colors.indigo700,
    accent1Color: Colors.redA200,
    pickerHeaderColor: Colors.darkBlack,
  },
  appBar: {
    height: 60,
  },
});

class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // MuiThemeProvider takes the theme as a property and passed it down the hierarchy
    // using React's context feature.
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
        <AppBar title="My AppBar">
       <div>
   < TextField hintText = "username" / >
    < TextField hintText = "password" / >

    </div>
    
        </AppBar>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

But, the palette styles override the `AppBar` 'title' color and no title is displaying. Should I include something or I have misplaced any ?

And this is my output :
[image]

Answer (score 51):

#### **Material UI v5** update

##### 1. Use `sx` prop

```
<AppBar sx={{ bgcolor: "green" }}>
```

##### 2. Set `primary.main` color in `Palette`

The `Appbar` background color uses the primary color provided from the theme by default.

```
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#00ff00"
    }
  }
});
```

##### 3. Set `AppBar` default styles in `styleOverrides`

Use this one if you don't want to touch the `primary.main` value and potentially affect other components:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiAppBar: {
      styleOverrides: {
        colorPrimary: {
          backgroundColor: "red"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This is the most complete and up-to-date answer for those using MUI v5.

Comment: I also found that if you're trying to set the background-color to black, you have to also set `backgroundImage: 'unset'` because for some reason MUI adds a subtle linear gradient to the `AppBar`.

Comment: Note: with dark mode, it does not color the appbar by default, see https://mui.com/material-ui/react-app-bar/#enable-color-on-dark

Comment: Note the latest release the app does not use the primary color anymore see [here](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-material/src/AppBar/AppBar.js#L39) Using style overides works

Comment: To fully change the color, I found it necessary to - as remarked above - remove the linear gradient. I accomplished this by specifying the style in the AppBar component: `<AppBar position="fixed" color="primary" style={{ backgroundImage: 'none', boxShadow: 'none' }}>`

Comment: It's saying components isn't a property of MuiAppBar

Answer (score 50):

If you ant to change your Appbar background in material ui design ....try following code

```
<AppBar style={{ background: '#2E3B55' }}>
```

or if you want to apply className then follow this step

first of all make create const var

```
const style = {

    background : '#2E3B55';
};

<AppBar className={style}>
```

Answer (score 16):

From what I see in the material-ui sources, appBar title color is set by palette.alternateTextColor. If you add it to your style definition like that:

```
const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    textColor: Colors.darkBlack,
    primary1Color: Colors.white,
    primary2Color: Colors.indigo700,
    accent1Color: Colors.redA200,
    pickerHeaderColor: Colors.darkBlack,
    alternateTextColor: Colors.redA200
  },
  appBar: {
    height: 60,
  },
});
```

You should see your title without need to style it manually inside each component.

There are more styling parameters to MuiTheme described [here](http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/themes)

Comment: Is it supposed to be exported? I created a similar thing in App.js following the imports, and no colors changed.

Comment: Ah, got it working, I forgot to add ``muiTheme={muiTheme}``  inside ``<MuiThemeProvider/>``

Answer (score 10):

Create your style using makeStyles():

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    boxShadow: "none",
    backgroundColor: "#cccccc" 
  } 
}));
```

Use the above style in your component:

```
const classes = useStyles();

<AppBar className={classes.root} />
```

Comment: I have the same and it does not work..

Answer (score 7):

- Please make theme.js first.

```
- theme.js
import { red } from '@material-ui/core/colors';
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

export default createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#556cd6',
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#19857b',
    },
    error: {
      main: red.A400,
    },
    background: {
      default: '#fff',
    },
  },
});
```

- Add these lines to index.js

```
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import theme from './theme'

ReactDOM.render(
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <App />    
  </ThemeProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```
<AppBar position='static' color='secondary' elevation={2}>
  ...
</AppBar>
```

*** important ***

```
secondary: {
  main: '#19857b',
},

color='secondary'
```

Comment: By far the most credible answer.

Answer (score 6):

Finally, I came to know about titleStyle for styling title in AppBar.

```
const titleStyles = {
  title: {
    cursor: 'pointer'

  },
  color:{
    color: Colors.redA200
  }
};
 <AppBar title={<span style={titleStyles.title}>Title</span>} titleStyle={titleStyles.color}> .............
</AppBar>
```

Answer (score 4):

By default it uses palette's contrastText prop (v3):

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      contrastText: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)'
    }
  },
});
```

Answer (score 3):

first of all, add const to the file. Then apply to the line u need as following shown.

```
const styles = { button: { margin: 15,}, appBarBackground:{ background : '#2E3B55' }};
```

Then add it to the line as shown down

```
 style={styles.button}
 style={styles.appBarBackground}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cat add this inline your code

```
<AppBar title="My AppBar" style={{ backgroundColor: '#2196F3' }} >
```

or if your css

```
import './home.css';
```

put this to your code

```
.title {
text-align: left;
background-color: black !important;}
```

Hope to help.

Answer (score 0):

Working on @NearHuscarl answer. If you want the styles to be applied no matter which appbar color you are on: E.g. `<Appbar color="secondary"` or `<Appbar color="primary"`. You could alternatively use the root property:

```js
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiAppBar: {
      root: {
        colorPrimary: {
          backgroundColor: "red"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

**The difference is the `root` keyword**

Answer (score 0):

You  can set the background color directly using `sx` property

```
<AppBar variant='elevated' sx={{backgroundColor:'#19857b'}}>
```